# Git Commit - Generate Commit Message for release note

Tags: git, github-actions, release

How can I generate git output like this way so I can put those changes in the project release note?

Is there any script or tool for that?

```
BREAKING CHANGES:

 - 3e4b520 [django]          

   Zsh already provides completion for the `django-admin` and `manage.py` commands, which is
   substantially better than the one provided by this plugin. We're therefore deprecating this
   plugin and we will remove it in the near future.

Features:

 - 4bd5d03 [golang]          Add `goga` alias to install dependencies in current directory, recursively (#7786)
 - 29ec526 [golang]          Add `gota` to test current directory recursively (#8974)
 - 7ded675 [jsontools]       Add tools to pretty print json-lines (ndjson) (#10176)
 - a4e6896 [lando]           Add support for `php` command (#10146)
 - 16de514 [lib]             Allow setting custom completion dots sequence (#9424)
 - 098bcda [update]          Allow updating from branch set up on install

Bug fixes:

 - d226918 [core]            Move plugin-generated completion files to `$ZSH_CACHE_DIR/completions`
 - 8784e88 [core]            Use `$HOME/.cache` if default cache dir is non-writable (#10193)
 - c21ff38 [docker]          Remove unwanted asterisk in completed docker commands
 - 4e6e496 [plugins]         Fix `_comps` error in completion generation plugins (#10190)
 - b79726b [update]          Silence `typeset` calls in `upgrade.sh` script (#10048)

Documentation:

 - 4d7f0cf [kubectx]         Fix README sample code syntax (#10199)

Other changes:

 - 93b557e [core]            Style: Make alternative cache directory equivalent to Arch Linux package
 - 3e4b520 [django]          Refactor: Deprecate plugin in favor of Zsh's django completion
 - 57e8c95 [installer]       Style: Use rainbow logo and polish success message (#10211)
 - b590939 [jsontools]       Refactor: Move to functions, align `is_json` tool to return exit code
 - f9d9d33 [jsontools]       Refactor: Restructure and simplify logic
 - eb2eaca [plugins]         Refactor: Remove old generated completion files
 - d87f29f [vim-interaction] Refactor: Clean up code and open gvim instance if none open (#10209)
```

Comment: what about ```git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit > RELEASE_NOTE```?

Answer (score 2):

That's the output displayed in Oh My Zsh when you run `omz changelog`, which is generated by the [`tools/changelog.sh` script](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/beeda72826f7288d3edf6cec4114bbda9bbae347/tools/changelog.sh) (I created it).

This changelog is automatically generated by parsing commit messages which follow the Conventional Commits specification.